# Wordpress | echo attribute_name and _value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using flatsome theme and i have a theme action hook called `flatsome_product_box_after`.
Basically he is located after the product picture on my Shop Catalogue.
Anyway: I managed to target the hook and `if` my products have the attribute `pa_hersteller` i want to `echo` the `attribute_name` and `attribute_value` of each product.
Right now i only have managed to `echo` "test". Any help to echo the attribute name and value is very appreciated. My Code so far:

```
function display_text_product_box_after() {
global $product;
 
       $hersteller = $product->get_attribute('pa_hersteller');
       if( ! empty($hersteller))
       {
          echo '<b style="color:black">test</b>';
       }

    }
 
 add_action('flatsome_product_box_after', 'display_text_product_box_after');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/374433/how-can-i-use-woocommerce-product-get-attribute-in-functions-php-if-at-all) may help you.

Basically, the `get_attribute()` may not be available for your `$product` variable because `$product` is not of `WC_Product` instance.